# Reading binary file in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to load the binary file to assembly and store it on the register.
Here is my C++ code where I load my file.

```
   extern "C" int turtle(unsigned char *commands, unsigned int commands_size);
 int main(void)
{
    FILE *fptr1;
    fptr1 = fopen("./input.bin", "rb+");

    fseek(fptr1, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned int length1 = ftell(fptr1);
    fseek(fptr1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char * buffer1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(length1 + 1);
    if (buffer1)
    {
        fread(buffer1, 1, length1, fptr1);
    }

    int result = turtle(buffer1, length1);
    printf("Returned value: %i ", result);

    fclose(fptr1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I do in assembly to check the value of register on which I load the value of my first element on unsigned char *commands. If the value is 1 I print the number of commands which is 1 and if the value on edx is not one it will print 0. Value of my binary file is:

> `00000001`
>   [image]

```
section .text
global  _turtle

_turtle:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, ecx        
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov edx, [eax]      ; 0 element
    mov ecx, edx

    cmp edx, 1
    je set1

set2:   
    mov ecx, [ebp + 12]
    mov eax, ecx        ;eax to ecx
    pop ebp
    ret
set1:
    mov eax, edx        ;eax to ecx
    pop ebp
    ret
```

The integer value seems to load properly, however the commands (chars) does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is C++ code, not C code.  Also note that you do not open the file as a binary file which might make a difference depending on platform (it does on Windows for example).

Comment: I've tried rb+ already, but it seems like it does make any influence. When I've printed the buffer1 the bits were same as in input file.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for anyway?

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Then this definitely does make a difference.  If your file is a binary file, always pass `b` in `fopen` to avoid Windows' weirdness with respect to text files.

Comment: When you check the value of the first element of the file, do you intend to check the first byte of the file? You’re reading a 32-bit integer, not a byte, and comparing it to 1.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the file as bytes? You seem to be showing it as a multi byte value. How many bytes are in the file, and what is the byte order?

Comment: If the first 4-byte element of the file is not equal to 1, turtle returns the number of bytes in the file, which doesn’t seem to match your description of the desired behavior.

Comment: You’re passing three parameters to turtle, even though it only takes two. I assume that’s a typo, since it shouldn’t compile.

Comment: 1) Basically my input file is just 00000001 so in byte it will be 01. 
2) That is a desired effect - i want to check the binary value - i just thought (I know it is not the smartest idea) to print this value.  
3) It's a typo

Comment: If the file contains only one byte, and turtle is reading four bytes, then the other three bytes may be garbage.

Comment: It looks to me that this always prints 1. Are you seeing a different value printed?

Comment: yes it always prints one. When i have added the 3 other bytes it seems to be working properly.